# Stack Overflow Annual Survey 2016

Tags: discussion

In the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2015 Results](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1946/102) Salesforce was rated as the Most Dreaded Tech.

[Vamsi](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3038/vamsi-krishna) has tweeted that the 2016 survey is now open.

You might like to go and share some of your thoughts there in the [Stack Overflow  Annual Survey 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2016).

Last Year [Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015)

[image]

Comment: I think they meant 'Most Feared' instead of 'Most Dreaded'! Let's kill it this time!!

Comment: Done my survey right now!

Comment: Done...most dreaded...whatever...

Comment: Done ..Thanks for the iinfo on survey

Comment: Done as well =]

Comment: Thanks for survey

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now that we're aware of this we might be able to put the record straight! Everybody, get on it!